# Chain rule multi-variable function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

*A $C^1$ function $f(x,y)$ defined in the area $x>0, \, y>0$ satisfies $$x\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = y \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}. $$
 Show that f is constant on all hyperbola branches $xy=c$ in the first quadrant.*

Let $z(x)=f(x,\frac{c}{x}), \, x>0$. The chain rules yields:
$$z'(x) = f'_x(x,\frac{c}{x}) \cdot 1 + f'_y(x,\frac{c}{x}) \cdot (\frac{-c}{x^2}) = \frac{1}{x}(xf'_x(x,\frac{c}{x})-\frac{c}{x}f'_y(x,\frac{c}{x}))$$
The book claims that by choosing $y=\frac{c}{x}$ the expression inside the big parenthesis is equal to $0$. I don't see how, could anyone explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the given,

$xf_x'-yf_y'=0$

But we have chosen $y=\frac{c}{x}$

Then, $xf'_x-\frac{c}{x}f'_y=0$

Since in your expression, the derivatives are evaluated at the same point, the resulting expression is equal to $0$.

QED.